# How many records a SQLiteDataReader or SqlDataReader can hold at a time?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqlite, sqldatareader

I just want to know,

> 1. Is there any size limit of SQLiteDataReader for holding records that mapped from Database?
> 2. Is there any difference between SQLiteDataReader and SqlDataReader about size limit for holding records?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically, a data reader is like a forward-only cursor - it fetches data from the database when it needs to, and yields data for one result at a time. Implementations may well fetch *batches* of results at a time, but that's largely hidden from clients: you see one result at a time, and you should be able to stream through very large data sets, without ever actually having very much data *in memory* on the client at any one time.

(Realistically, I'd suggest that it's *usually* not a great idea to stream billions of rows in a single query, but it depends on your context.)

Comment: Jon thanks for your valuable suggestion. i dont want to stream billions of row in a single query. just the question is running on my head. but recently i have to done a work "getting all data from database contains billions of records of same type and process them". which means i can read them with a single query.

Comment: Jon Could you please just tell me is there any possiblity to crash a datareader while featching billions of data (if all data are valid)

Comment: @Rezoan: If the reader has been implemented correctly, and there aren't other factors involved (such as the connection dying) it should be fine.